# Is it possible to condition a default value in the constructor depending on another value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, lit-element

I want to set a defalt value in the constructor depends on other value.

Here is the template where the type values ​​are:

```
class SelectOption extends LitElement {
static get properties() {
    return {
        type: {type: Array}
    };
}

constructor() {
    super();
    this.type = ['1', '2'];
}
```

This is more or less what I want:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class SelectCounter extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
             type: {type: Array},
             numPassengers: {type: Number},
         };
     }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.numPassengers = {
            if (this.type === '1') {
                this.numPassengers = 1;
            } else {
                this.numPassengers = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use ternary `this.numPassengers = this.type === '1' ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Always return 0.

Comment: `this.type === '1'` always evaluates to false: you're comparing an array with a string. Maybe you meant `this.type.includes('1')`?

Answer (score 0):

Not from the constructor, no.  When the constructor is called, the properties haven't been set from the DOM yet.  I recommend checking inside [firstUpdated](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#firstupdated).

However, a couple other things to consider.

First, the expression for evaluating `this.numPassengers` is a bit off.  I can't quite see from the two examples what you want, but if `type` was meant to be an array, consider the following snippet:

```js
const thisType = ['1', '2'];
let thisNumPassengers;
if (thisType[0] === '1') {
    thisNumPassengers = 1;
} else {
    thisNumPassengers = 0;
}
console.log(thisNumPassengers);
```

But I think you should specifically ask yourself "what is `type`?" and "what is `numPassengers`?" as it's not clear in your examples what you were intending.

To help you on the path to victory, I'll include a snippet below with a `debugger` in it.  I recommend you run the code via `polymer serve` or `es-dev-server` or another development server, open the code with **Inspect** opened in your browser and walk through the debugger breakpoint to see if you can resolve the issue:

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class SelectCounter extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
             type: {type: Array},
             numPassengers: {type: Number},
         };
     }

    firstUpdated() {
        console.log(this.type);
        this.numPassengers = 'fix me';
        debugger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want if you pass `type` as an argument to the constructor. You can evaluate `type` and conditionally set the value `this.numPassengers` based on it's value - you can achieve this using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
class SelectCounter {
  constructor(type) {
    this.numPassengers = type === '1' ? 1 : 0
  }
}

const sc0 = new SelectCounter();
const sc1 = new SelectCounter('1');

console.log(sc0.numPassengers);
console.log(sc1.numPassengers);
```